# MongoDB - Getting started with MongoDB Community and Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm following the [official steps](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-community-with-docker/#std-label-docker-mongodb-community-install) outlined at MongoDB's site to get MongoDB running with Docker.

I've followed the steps (almost) to the letter.

```
$ docker pull mongodb/mongodb-community-server:6.0-ubuntu2204
```

```
$ docker run --name mongodb-6.0 --platform=linux/amd64 -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mongodb/mongodb-community-server:6.0-ubuntu2204
```

And, then ... I'm stuck! I cannot connect with `mongosh`.

```
$ docker exec -it mongo-6.0 mongosh -u admin -p password
Current Mongosh Log ID: 643ddf8b9d8b6b3b6b4bc7d1
Connecting to:      mongodb://<credentials>@127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.8.0
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Hmm... okay. So, I *don't* have the `mongod` service running?

Well, using `docker ls` I know I've got the container running...

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                      NAMES
5e4092196022   mongodb/mongodb-community-server:6.0.5-ubi8   "python3 /usr/local/…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongo
```

And I'm pretty sure I *do* have `mongod` running

```
$ docker exec mongo-6.0 ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mongodb      1  0.0  0.5 172248 43688 ?        Ssl  00:00   0:00 /usr/bin/qemu-x86_64 /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.py mongo
mongodb     11  100  0.4 281104 33772 ?        Rl   00:00   9:51 /usr/bin/qemu-x86_64 /usr/bin/mongod /usr/bin/mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 -
mongodb     55  0.0  0.1 151596  9808 ?        Rl+  Apr17   0:00 ps aux
```

So, I have no idea how to continue to troubleshoot. Help! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is an M1 Apple Silicon problem.

As you can see in the question, I passed the `--platform=linux/amd64` flag after getting errors.

I retried all of my steps on an Intel based Mac and had no issues at all.

So, instead of using the [Community Edition](https://hub.docker.com/r/mongodb/mongodb-community-server) image, I'm using the [Docker official image for MongoDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo). ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

```bash
docker exec -it mongodb-6.0 mongosh -u admin -p password
```