# Connect to mongodb container from host: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, connection, localhost

I am trying to build a multi-container docker-compose file. But I want to do it step by step. First step is to run a mongodb docker container and connect to it from localhost.

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongodb/mongodb-community-server:6.0.4-ubi8
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
      - MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

I run it using `docker-compose --verbose up` and obtain the following output :

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container smart-quiz-mongodb-1  Created                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
Attaching to smart-quiz-mongodb-1
```

I try to connect to it using `docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID>  mongosh -u user -p pass` on another terminal, I get the following output :

```
Current Mongosh Log ID: 64526ee0956e32093ceff7ed
Connecting to:      mongodb://<credentials>@127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.8.2
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Could you help me to solve this ?

I checked that I set the ports correctly in the docker-compose.yml file and to my understanding it is.

I checked that I do not have another local instance of mongodb running on the same port (27017) and no local mongodb instance is running.

Comment: Update : according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76041061/20512742) it may be a problem related to M1 Apple Silicon...

Comment: Solved ! Using the official mongo docker image works perfectly.